# I want rules to be overwritten

Tags: css

I have two lists in my page. The first one in the `#main` element, and the second one in the `#footer` element. Since the `#footer` element is inside the `#main` element these are my rules:

```css
body div#wrap_all div#main div#footer div.widget_nav_menu ul#menu-footer li {
    border-right: 1px solid #D2AB67;
    display: inline-block !important;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
/* I dont want this rules below to be applied to the list in the footer */
body div#wrap_all div#main section.avia_widget_section ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0D3CD;
    font-family: "Georgia";
    font-size: 17px;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 7px 0 0 22px; /* O_o this rule is overwritten of course */
}
```

The problem: the rules of the first list are also applied to the list in the `.footer` element. What can I do to avoid that?

Comment: You don't need layered selectors with IDs, the first can just be `#menu-footer li` and the second can be `#main section.avia_widget_section ul li`. Also, we need to see your HTML structure

Answer (score 1):

The first selector obviously has more scores than the second one, so I simply suggest making the second rule more precise by defining more steps in the selector.

The ugly solution, of course, is to use `!important` at the end of your css value:

```
padding: 7px 0 0 22px !important;
```

But I strongly recommend rewriting your css selector instead of using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the :not() selector.

```
body div#wrap_all div#main section.avia_widget_section :not(#footer) ul li {
}
```

or reset the specific rule :

```
body div#wrap_all div#main section.avia_widget_section #footer ul li {
padding:0; /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: replace :not(#footer) or #footer according to you html structure