# Trying to overwrite a rule

Tags: css

I expected the upper rule overwrites the second one, but no.. why?

```
body div#wrap_all header#header div#header_main div.container nav.main_menu div.avia-menu ul:first-child > li a {
    height: 50px !important;
}

#header_main .container, .main_menu ul:first-child > li a {
    height: 88px;
}
```

Comment: I am almost sure that the 1st rule is not been applied.

Comment: Can you post some code using these rules? Btw, try to remove the "body div" from the beginning of your first rule and put an espace between "header" and "#header".

Comment: @Unykvis And wt is the reason for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want rules to be overwritten](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265452/i-want-rules-to-be-overwritten)

Comment: Because if it were the first rule should be overlapping like you expected to.

Comment: @Unykvis what is the "reason" the 1st rule is not being applied? I can see it in Firebug

Answer (score 2):

You should calculate the specificity of your CSS rules in order to find out why one is taken over another:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

> 100 for each ID, add 10 for each attribute, class or pseudo-class, add
>   1 for each element name or pseudo-element

Additionally, using the `!important` flag should absolutely ensure it is more specific than your second rule:

> An !important declaration provides a way for a stylesheet author to
>   give a CSS value more weight than it naturally has

I would imagine if this is still not the case, there is a `style` attribute or third party script getting in the way.

Comment: so the first one is more specific, so it should overwrite the second one..but that is not my case..

Comment: Correct. I would like to see a Fiddle of this in action if possible as I can't imagine any circumstance where the second would come out on top, especially given your !important flag.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xJ4EG/ As you say the second one is not being applied, but why in my code is being applied?

Comment: @ziiweb Your CSS is not the issue. The issue lies in your HTML markup

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45799/discussion-between-ziiweb-and-rgraham)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the second rule to the first line:

```
body div#wrap_all header#header div#header_main div.container nav.main_menu div.avia-menu      ul:first-child > li a,
.main_menu ul:first-child > li a{
   height: 50px !important;
}
```

If this works this means that the first rule is not being applied otherwise it should be overriding.